# Inputting a list of duplicated values into the value for a dictionary with a certain key

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary`dict` where each item has a key `key`taken from a list `keylist` and a value `valuelist` that contains a `word` from list `wordlist` repeated `n` number of times.
I already have a way to get `keylist,wordlist,`and `n`.

I already have a dictionary in the form:
`(key,word):n`

If the inputs were

- `key`= "A"
- `word` = "OK"
- `n` = 3

Therefore, the form of the dictionary result that I want is:

`{(key):[word*n`(each n instance of `word` is a separate list entry)`]}`

The resultant dictionary `dict` from my example that I want would be:

`{("A"):["OK","OK","OK"]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
dic = {('A', 'OK'): 3, ('B', 'NOT OK'): 2}
out = {key: [word]*n for ((key, word), n) in dic.iteritems()}
# {'A': ['OK', 'OK', 'OK'], 'B': ['NOT OK', 'NOT OK']}
```

where `dic` is your dictionary with `(key, word): n`.

If you want to keep the same tuple as a key, you can do:

```
out = {(key, word): [word]*n for ((key, word), n) in dic.iteritems()}
# {('A', 'OK'): ['OK', 'OK', 'OK'], ('B', 'NOT OK'): ['NOT OK', 'NOT OK']}
```

Comment: Thanks! As a follow-up, if I wanted to use two words as a key, what would I add to the code that you posted?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure if that's what you meant by "two words as a key" but see my edit.

Comment: More along the lines of what I meant was how would I go about assembling a trigram, if the previous code was  a bigram. If I wanted to have a key that is two words